# iphone - Check validity and expiration of APNS certificate

Tags: java, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to write some java code to check for validity and expiration date of an APNS certificate. I have scoured the net for examples and have not found any. Is it possible to do that? Could someone point me to examples/tutorials if it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` :

```
public abstract void checkValidity()
                            throws CertificateExpiredException,
                                   CertificateNotYetValidException
```

> Checks that the certificate is currently valid. It is if the current
>   date and time are within the validity period given in the certificate.